# Graylog2 custom message to telegram

Tags: graylog2, graylog

I want custom message send to telegram, but i recive empty message. 
ex:

```
Graylog2:
%message.id%
Source: %source%
Name: %name%
Name: ${name}
```

Thanks.

Comment: See the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: For reference: https://community.graylog.org/t/how-to-send-fields-message-to-telegram/4617

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code inside message field of plugin:

````
[${stream.title}](${stream_url})
${foreach backlog message}
```${message.message}```
${end}
````